# how to check member type when having hierarchical inheritance

Tags: database, oop

I have the following structure : 
Person (abstract class) inherited by admin,staff and candidate. The candidate has two subclasses : admitted and retained.
So when a "person" sign in, I have to check if he's admin, staff or candidate, and if he is candidate I have to check if he's admitted,retained or just candidate, that means that I have to check 4 to 6 table each time someone sign in and in addition I will have to make a lot of if else in my program (to create the appropriate instance), I thought to go for a TPH but the problem is that some subclasses have relationships with other classes that some other don't have for example admin have a relation with "Processing result" (he's allowed to consult the processing results, and this will be logged in the database)
So what's the best solution to check member type in this case? is it possible to add a discriminator column in TPT ? can it be a foreign key  (like putting all types in a table and put references to this types in the person and candidate table) ?

Thank you :)

Comment: what does TPH and TPT mean?

Comment: Table per hierarchy and Table per type

Comment: So, you want to represent the hierarchy of your classes in the database. You are thinking in the opposite direction of most people: usually we have an initial db model that needs to turn into a class model. Now, if you are starting from class model, why not use a NoSQL or Object database? Then, this problem will not happen.

Comment: That's because I started with a UML modelization, concerning your suggestion I've never used any of these databases before, and I have only one month to finish this project, is it easy to learn NoSQl/Object database? What are the pros/cons of using them? and how they will help me resolving my problem?